# Database structure for account transactions

Tags: database-design

i have created a database to store customer banking transactions. i am currecntly storing all th trasactions in one table with columns for the cust_id, tran_no, tran_date and so on.

Currently my database is small since i am only testing it and it works properly. I perform queries to get transactions by date and also sum of transactions by customer.

My question is, is it ok to maintain all the transactions in one table. Do i need to split the transactions for each customer in seperate tables.

Comment: Are you really asking if having 1000 customers and corresponding 1000 database tables is good design?

Comment: yes. I dont know if having all the transactions in one table is a good idea?

Comment: @vijay.richards: Well, having one transaction table per customer is a perfectly terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to keep the transactions for all of your customers in one table.  Relational database tools are very good at filtering large data sets.  Having an index on the customer ID will make it very easy and efficient to retrieve the transactions for a particular customer.

If you split your transactions into one table per customer then your queries to retrieve customer data and your process for establishing a new customer will be more complex, difficult to maintain and time consuming.